# Не правильно работает parseInt при переводе в бинарный код

Tags: java

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Vvedite chislo a: ");
String a = in.nextLine();
System.out.print("Vvedite chislo b: ");
String b = in.nextLine();
int inta = Integer.parseInt(a, 2);
int intb = Integer.parseInt(b, 2);
```

`Vvedite chislo a: 12`

`Vvedite chislo b: 23`

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "12"  at
>   java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)   at
>   edu.Atom.Main.main(Main.java:22)

Comment: В двоичной системе счисления не может быть двоек.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev так я же в двоичную хочу перевести, поэтому и указываю 2

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev [кажется, я видел двойку](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=60cDFT_7rVg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не переводите в бинарный код, а делаете ровно наоборот, хотите число из двоичного перевести в десятичное.

Для перевода в бинарный код нужно пользоваться методом `toBinaryString` либо `toString`:

```
Integer.toBinaryString(a); //где a - десятичное число с типом int
//или
Integer.toString(a, 2);
```